# Modular application generic DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.6.1

I want to pass a list/dictionary of generic parameter (that can be different types in the same collection) to a method in a modular application.
I hope my code can explain it better.

The interfaces:

```
public interface IField
{ }

public interface IField<T> : IField
{
    T Value { get; }
}
```

The implemented class:

```
public class Field<T> : IField<T>
{      
    public Field(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can create a Dictionary with my parameters and call a method that is implemented in a different assembly not referenced (I get it using reflection):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dicFields = new Dictionary<string, IField>();
    dicFields.Add("param1", new Field<string>("Hello"));
    dicFields.Add("param2", new Field<int>(15));

    MyMethod(dicFields);
}
```

Now, in 'MyMethod', I want to get the value for a specific parameter in the dictionary:

```
public void MyMethod(IDictionary<string, IField> parameters)
{
    var param2 = parameters["param2"];
}
```

The problem is that 'param2' has not the property Value (generic type) because I used the IField interface to define the dictionary elements and in 'MyMethod' we can't know the right implementation of the parameter.

Any suggestion to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics do not work this way.

To get the Generic Types, you need to use the `IField<T>` interface in your dictionary and your method.

However, you aren't going to be able to mix types because when you create an instance of a class you IField will be restricted to only T:

```
public interface IField
{

}
public interface IField<T> : IField
{
    T Value { get; }
}
public class Field<T> : IField<T>
{
    public Field(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
public void Generic()
{

    var dicFields = new Dictionary<string, IField<string>>();
    dicFields.Add("param1", new Field<string>("Hello"));
    dicFields.Add("param2", new Field<string>("Hello"));

    MyMethod<String>(dicFields);

}
public void MyMethod<T>(IDictionary<string, IField<T>> parameters)
{
    var param2 = parameters["param2"].Value;
}
```

If you wanted to mix types you would need to use IField which will require you to box and unbox your types:

public interface IField
    {

```
}
public interface IField<T> : IField
{
    T Value { get; }
}
public class Field<T> : IField<T>
{
    public Field(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
public void Generic()
{

    var dicFields = new Dictionary<string, IField<object>>();
    dicFields.Add("param1", new Field<object>("Hello"));
    dicFields.Add("param2", new Field<object>(2));

    MyMethod<object>(dicFields);

}
public void MyMethod<T>(IDictionary<string, IField<T>> parameters)
{
    var param2 = parameters["param2"].Value;
}
```

While it is considered bad practice, you could use a `Dictionary<string, Dynamic>`

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
dict.Add("value1", "a");
dict.Add("value2", 2);
dict.Add("value3", 3);
int result = dict["value2"] + dict["value3"];
```

Comment: Thank you for the full answer. I finally realized I can not do it using generics.

Answer (score 0):

One way to manage what you're trying to do is to add access methods to `IField` that will allow you to get an `object` value and the type.

```
public interface IField
{
  object GetValue { get; }
  Type GetValueType();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I will go down this road.